# Why won't the message box appear?

Tags: java, messagebox

I am trying to make a message box appear when the user achieves tic tac toe. Currently there is an error that highlights the closing bracket of the method and says there is a missing return statement. This is the class that determines if there is a win and displays the message box.

```
public boolean checkRows()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (checkRowCol(board[i][0], board[i][1], board[i][2]) == true)
        {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win", "Title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
        else if (checkRowCol(board[i][0], board[i][1], board[i][2]) ==  false)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I am not sure why it is saying there is a missing return statement.

Comment: What should `checkRows` return if `checkRowCol(board[i][0], board[i][1], board[i][2])` is true?

Answer (score 0):

Your method asks a boolean as result.
If the first statement is true, you execute the ShowMessageDialogue method but right after that, the function is still waiting for you to return a boolean.
I don't know how your code works, but it seems like this would work:

```
 public void checkRows()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
        if (checkRowCol(board[i][0], board[i][1], board[i][2]) == true)
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Win", "Title",
             JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

 }
```

Make your tictactoe game call this method every time the user executes a move: if he has won, the checkRows method will show the "You win" message, otherwise it will do nothing and the user can do the next move

Answer (score 0):

The java compiler complains because it does not think all code paths return a boolean. (Even if it does so in this case) 
You can fix this by adding a `return false;` before closing the method. A better solution might be to use

```
else return false;
```

Instead of

```
else if (checkRowCol(board[i][0], board[i][1], board[i][2]) == false) { return false; }
```

This way, the function will always return a boolean.